Problems encountered when installing new solver
When I used
conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver
conda config --set solver libmamba

These two commands to install and set the new solver，i thought everything was fine.But when I try to install e.g. numpy package, I got the error
CondaValueError: You have chosen a non-default solver backend (libmamba) but it was not recognized. Choose one of: classic

active environment : base
    active env location : D:\Anaconda
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\35108\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\35108\.condarc
          conda version : 23.1.0
    conda-build version : 3.22.0
         python version : 3.9.13.final.0

Conda Config
==> C:\Users\35108.condarc <==
channels:
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/
  - defaults
show_channel_urls: True
solver: libmamba

I don't know how to solve it

The version 23.1.0 of conda is probably very old (from January 2023, I guess). Can you update conda using the regular conda solver then try again?

Desperately I use
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
conda install conda=24.4.0
Both commands fail to update conda correctly because there are too many package conflicts. On the official website, I saw that anaconda has used libmamba as the default solver. It seems I can only uninstall anaconda and then reinstall a higher version. But I'm worried that uninstalling anaconda will make my Python environment more messy.

I don't know about more messy... but it seems if you want the new solver you need to use the new Anaconda, and it seems your way to do that is to reinstall Anaconda. Sorry I can't be more help!
